# getwindowHandle() throwing Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) error

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

While implementing getwindowhandles in android web browser , i am getting an error "Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

Scenario is : i need to switch to next tab and get the url and close it.

Comment: Can you update the question with code sample? Which line is throwing the error and what instance of driver(WebDriver or AndroidDriver) are you creating?

Comment: public static AndroidDriver driver;  String handle  = driver.getWindowHandle(); -> error is thrown here.   @BountyHunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to perform `getWindowHandle()` operation on native app context due to which the appium may be throwing "Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

Here is how you can troubleshoot and fix this:

Add the following lines before `String handle = driver.getWindowHandle();`

```
//Get all available contexts
Set<String> contexts=driver.getContextHandles();
//Review available contexts on console
System.out.println(contexts);

//Iterate through the contexts
for(String context :contexts){
    //Check if the context is webview. If yes, then switch to that context
    if(context.toLowerCase().contains("webview")||context.toLowerCase().contains("web_view")){
        driver.context(context);
        //break the loop if webview context is found and driver switches to webview context
        break;
        }
    }
```